# number of students in a class

Tags: linear-algebra

> A third-grade teacher has $n$ boxes, each containing 12 pencils. After the teacher gives $p$ pencils to each student in the class, the teacher has $t$ pencils left over. Which of the following represents the number of students in the class?
>
> a. $\frac{12n - t}{p}$
> b. $\frac{12n + t}{p}$
> c. $\frac{12n}{p} - t$
> d. $\frac{12p - t}{n}$
> e. $\frac{12p + t}{n}$

The answer given is A. Any tips on how I can solve this question?

Comment: Did you start by writing an equation for it? Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of pencils is $12 \times n$. 
If there are $s$ students, and each one receives $p$ pencils, a total of $p \times s$ pencils are given, and hence the teacher is left with $12  \times n - p \times s$ pencils, which (we are told) is $t$.

Then $$t =  12 \times n - p \times s$$

so the total number of students ($s$) is given by

$$ s = \frac{12 \times n - t }{p}$$

Let me know if there something you don't get.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use these three relationships to solve for the number of students:
$$\newcommand{\tsf}[1]{\mathsf{\text{#1}}}
\begin{align}
\tsf{total number of pencils} &= \tsf{number of pencils given to students} + \tsf{number of pencils left over}\\[0.1in]
\tsf{total number of pencils} &= \tsf{number of boxes of pencils} \times \tsf{number of pencils per box}\\[0.1in]
\end{align}$$
$$\tsf{number of pencils given to students}=\tsf{number of students}\times\tsf{number of pencils each student got}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Let $s$ be the number of students
2. How many pencils are there in total?
3. How many pencils were given out?
4. What is the difference between the answers to (2) and (3)?
5. If you set the number of pencil left over $t$ equal to the answer to (4), and solve for $s$, what do you get?